Fortran compilation fails with "Cannot open module file 'mkl_service.mod'" when using Intel MKL in Conda environment
I'm trying to compile a simple Fortran program that uses Intel's Math Kernel Library (MKL) in a Conda environment. However, I'm encountering an error where the compiler can't find the mkl_service.mod file. Here are the details:
Environment:

OS: Ubuntu (latest LTS)
Conda environment with:

gfortran 14.1.0 (conda-forge)
MKL 2024.2.0 (intel_663 build)



Files:

test_mkl.f90:

program main
  use mkl_service
  implicit none
  print *, "MKL module loaded successfully"
end program main


Makefile:

CONDA_ENV := mpsd

CONDA_ACTIVATE := source $$(conda info --base)/etc/profile.d/conda.sh ; conda activate

SETUP_SCRIPT := ./setup.sh

SHELL := /bin/bash
.SHELLFLAGS := -ec

FORT = gfortran
FLAGS = -fdefault-integer-8 -O3 -m64 -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wunused -std=gnu
INCLUDE = -I$(MKLROOT)/include -I$(CONDA_PREFIX)/include -I$(CONDA_PREFIX)/include/intel64/lp64
LIBS = -L$(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64 -lmkl_gf_ilp64 -lmkl_gnu_thread -lmkl_core -lgomp -lpthread -lm -ldl

EXE = test_mkl

.PHONY: all clean print_versions

all: activate_env print_versions $(EXE)

activate_env:
    @echo "Activating Conda environment and running setup script"
    @$(CONDA_ACTIVATE) $(CONDA_ENV) && source $(SETUP_SCRIPT)

print_versions:
    @echo "Checking Fortran compiler version:"
    @$(CONDA_ACTIVATE) $(CONDA_ENV) && $(FORT) --version
    @echo "Checking MKL version:"
    @$(CONDA_ACTIVATE) $(CONDA_ENV) && conda list | grep mkl

$(EXE): test_mkl.f90
    @echo "Compiling and linking $(EXE)"
    $(CONDA_ACTIVATE) $(CONDA_ENV) && source $(SETUP_SCRIPT) && \
    $(FORT) $(FLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $< -o $@ $(LIBS)

clean:
    @echo "Cleaning up"
    @rm -f $(EXE)


setup.sh:

#!/bin/bash

export MKLROOT=$CONDA_PREFIX
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MKLROOT/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export CPATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/include:$CPATH
export INCLUDE_PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/include
export FPATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/include:$FPATH
export MKL_INCLUDE=$CONDA_PREFIX/include

echo "MKLROOT: $MKLROOT"
echo "CPATH: $CPATH"
echo "INCLUDE_PATH: $INCLUDE_PATH"
echo "FPATH: $FPATH"
echo "MKL_INCLUDE: $MKL_INCLUDE"

environment.yml
name: mpsd
channels:
  - intel
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.12
  - mkl
  - mkl-include
  - mkl-devel
  - intel-fortran-rt
  - gfortran
  - make

Error:
When I run make, I get the following error:
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory '/include' [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory '/include' [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory '/include/intel64/lp64' [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
test_mkl.f90:3:7:

    3 |   use mkl_service
      |       1
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file 'mkl_service.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [makefile:33: test_mkl] Error 1

What I've Tried:

Reinstalling MKL in the Conda environment
Checking that the MKL module files exist in the expected locations

➜ ls $CONDA_PREFIX/include/intel64/lp64

blas95.mod  f95_precision.mod  lapack95.mod  mkl_service.mod



Verifying that the MKLROOT and other environment variables are set correctly

Questions:

Why can't the compiler find the mkl_service.mod file?
Are there any compatibility issues between gfortran 14.1.0 and MKL 2024.2.0?
How can I resolve this issue and successfully compile my program?


The Nonexistent include directory '/include' error message may imply that the MKLROOT variable is not defined.

The error messages about the .mod files may imply that they appear in the the gfortran compilation command, but they should not. But it's difficult to really help you without seeing the actual gfortran command that is executed

If I understand correctly the $^F syntax is referencing the files that are given as dependencies, so including the .mod files. Actually, the .mod should not even be dependencies for the link stage, they are possibly dependencies only for the compilation stage (build the .o files). But since you are using existing .mod files that you don't generate nor modify, you don't have at all to put them in the dependencies, you just have to make them accessible.

The modula2 stuff is almost certainly due to some default in make thinking .mod files are for modula2, not Fortran modules. had similar to this before, but rushing out now. When get back if nobody has answered will see if I can find the solution (the best solution is move on from make to something more modern...)

@PierU, I've added the full makefile for your reference. Thanks for everyone's comments. This is giving some good ideas for stuff to investigate further.

I insist: a .mod file should not appear in any compilation or link command.

I've simplified the question so others can try and build it locally and see if they can see what is wrong in their environments.

I've added the ls statement for your review.

I think the root of your problem is the set of missing include directory issues flagged by the compiler.  It seems like make is maybe not picking up the CONDA_PREFIX environment var for some reason.

Very good, @PierU.  I agree with you, but it's irrelevant.  I don't see any reason to think that a .mod file does appear in any of the compilation or link commands -- though that would be clearer if the question included the parts of the make output that actually show the commands being executed.  The compiler goes looking for such a file (and fails to find it) as a consequence of a use statement in the Fortran source.

@JohnBollinger The OP has edited the question. In the first version there were .mod files that were appearing on the link command.

There is a confusion between environment variables, makefile variables, and subshell variables. MKLROOT for instance is set in a subshell that executes source $(SETUP_SCRIPT), is immediately lost, and is not available as a makefile variable to build the INCLUDE variable. What you should do is rather: source ./setup.sh && make

Regarding the compatibility between MKL and gfortran: the "*.mod" are compiler dependent. The ones of the MKL have likely been generated with the Intel Fortran compiler, and therefore can be USEd only from sources compiled with the Intel compiler as well.
